# How do I return the color of a character in Excel when executing a Macro?

Tags: excel, vba, colors, character

On Sheet1 of my Excel worksheet, I have used the Data Validation option to create drop down choices for a user. For example, a user might select a red cross or a biohazard symbol with a yellow background (see Segoe UI Symbol).Although I have color coded the original data options, when a user clicks the drop down, they only see black and white for either option. The simple option seems to be to use conditional formatting on those cells which will have the drop down. However, I have also created a macro to reproduce these characters on Sheet2. While the macro does reproduce the character, the character does not retain any of the original color formatting.

I am providing some of the coding below to help understand what I have done. Please note that L1 through L5 represents specification for a shape's left start point. Vrb1 through Vrb5 represents the character that I would like reproduced.

The general idea is that a process flowchart will be produced. Next to each step, there could be up to 5 images produced (Vrb1 through Vrb5).

Thank you in advance for your help!

```
For Each rng In ws1.Range("CS3:CS22")
    L1 = rng.Value
    L2 = rng.Offset(, 1).Value
    L3 = rng.Offset(, 2).Value
    L4 = rng.Offset(, 3).Value
    L5 = rng.Offset(, 4).Value
    Top = rng.Offset(, 5).Value
    Width = rng.Offset(, 6).Value
    Height = rng.Offset(, 7).Value
    Vrb1 = rng.Offset(, -87).Value
    Vrb2 = rng.Offset(, -85).Value
    Vrb3 = rng.Offset(, -83).Value
    Vrb4 = rng.Offset(, -81).Value
    Vrb5 = rng.Offset(, -79).Value



    Select Case rng.Offset(, -87).Value
        Case Is <> 0
            Set shp = ws2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, L1, Top, Width, Height)
                With shp
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = Vrb1
                    .LinkFormat.Locked = False
                    .TextFrame.MarginBottom = 0
                    .TextFrame.MarginLeft = 0
                    .TextFrame.MarginRight = 0
                    .TextFrame.MarginTop = 0
                    .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                    .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.FontStyle = "Arial"
                    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 23
                    .ShapeStyle = msoLineStylePreset1
                    .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)

                End With

                End Select
```

Comment: DV drop-downs won't pick up colors or other formatting.  If you need that you'll have to use a different approach.

Comment: Thank you, Tim Williams!

Comment: If you need to pick up a color from a cell which has color applied through Conditional Formatting, look at the `DisplayFormat` property.

Comment: Again, thank you, Tim! I expect that the code I am writing will constantly be changing...for the better I hope. I took a different route. On sheet one, a user, for example, might select "Medical Mistake". On the same sheet and in another cell, that gets translated into a cross. I wrote my code such that the cross is displayed in a text box, but I also used the "Select Case" to create a condition that the textbox will have a red background. I will keep your suggestion in mind as I update the code.